# How to resolve android.opengl.Object3D dependency in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, undefined-symbol

I'm in a quest to build an old application for android 4.4 target framework, imported the project correctly and on build it says cannot resolve Object3D. 
It seems like the latest android.opengl don't have Object3D class.

I got the source code for Object3D class, made a jar file out of it and added it to project dependency but no luck please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you download `android-src.jar` in this link

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-src/android-src.jar.zip